# Select onChange not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi there i have used this Custom Select Menu from here http://codepen.io/wallaceerick/pen/ctsCz

The issue now i am facing is my select onChange function is not working Basically when we select first option it get data in second select based on first selection it was working before i used this custom select menu so i think the issue is with this custom select menu Javascript code

Select Menu Code

```
          <div class="select">
              <select name="province" id="selProvinces_{$sn}" onchange="region.changed(this, 2, 'selCities_{$sn}')">
                <option value="0">{$lang.please_select}{$name_of_region[1]}</option>
                <!-- {foreach from=$province_list.$sn item=province} -->
                <option value="{$province.region_id}" {if $consignee.province eq $province.region_id}selected{/if}>{$province.region_name}</option>
                <!-- {/foreach} -->
              </select>
          </div>
```

Javascript

```
    $('select').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this), numberOfOptions = $(this).children('option').length;

        $this.addClass('select-hidden'); 
        $this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');
        $this.after('<div class="select-styled"></div>');

        var $styledSelect = $this.next('div.select-styled');
        $styledSelect.text($this.children('option').eq(0).text());

        var $list = $('<ul />', {
            'class': 'select-options'
        }).insertAfter($styledSelect);

        for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
            $('<li />', {
                text: $this.children('option').eq(i).text(),
                rel: $this.children('option').eq(i).val()
            }).appendTo($list);
        }

        var $listItems = $list.children('li');

        $styledSelect.click(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            $('div.select-styled.active').not(this).each(function(){
                $(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.select-options').hide();
            });
            $(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.select-options').toggle();
        });

        $listItems.click(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
            $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
            $list.hide();
            //console.log($this.val());
        });

        $(document).click(function() {
            $styledSelect.removeClass('active');
            $list.hide();
        });

});
```

Comment: Please 1: Click `<>` and create a [mcve] without templating then 2: explain what you mean exactly with "Not Working" -  errors in console? What? For example `$('select').each(function(){` does likely not do what you think it does.

Comment: Basically when we select first option it get data in second select based on first selection it was working before i used this custom select menu so i think the issue is with this custom select menu

Comment: I dont think your code i matching with the problem you are asking about. am not able to see any where onchange is called

Comment: onchange="region.changed(this, 2, 'selCities_{$sn}')">